# How to set the frame shape of a QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I just cannot grasp the enum in class concept syntactically. 
I am trying to disable QTextEdit's frame:

```
//in a header for my custom class where the main element is the textField

QTextEdit* textField;
...

//displaying it myCustomClass.cpp
textField = new QTextEdit(this);
textField->Shape = QFrame::NoFrame;
```

I get the error "invalid use of enum::Qframe::Shape". What is the correct syntax and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's invalid C++: there's no such "Shape" member for QTextEdit. Moreover, **Qt uses proper encapsulation**, so the shape is *not* exposed by a member variable.

You have to call a method which sets the frame shape, and *surprisingly enough*, it's called `setFrameShape`!

```
textField->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
```

Comment: so we have setters for that stuff in Qt!OK!